# Strength and conditioning for blood circulation

Tags: cardio, blood-flow

Resources online primarily focus on cardio being the best way to improve blood flow. However, some resources also mention strength and conditioning for improved blood flow. I have noticed that pushups and similar exercises do get my heart pumping.

How good are strength and conditioning training compared to cardio to improve blood flow while I am not training? Is there any research on how much impact intensity of workout has on a persons blood circulation?

That is, how much better is one hour of brisk walking compared to twelve minutes of guerilla cardio training if my goal is to improve my overall blood circulation?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you been tested for [Raynaud's disease](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/raynauds-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20363571)?

Comment: If you think your brain is not getting enough nutrition, it is a huge condition that you need to check with a specialized doctor. If a doctor told you this, and he should have referred to people of relevant profession, whether it is a dietitian or physical therapist. I think neither SE nor other online resources are a good place to learn about this.

Comment: The question is not about my brain; it's about blood flow. I know what the issue with my brain is, and I am removing that paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. If considered 1 hour training - running can be better. Why? You burn much more calories then in other trainings, so your blood needs to deal with all of that. I mean oxygen, nutrition, and removing wastes. My heart says it works pretty hard, when I run, sometimes trying to escape...

For shorter trainings - rowing? or maybe stationary bike with moving arms? That are exercises, which deals with many muscles at once. Amount of energy produced in short period of time can be quite impressive. And that mean some work for blood as well.

Strength training, with rest for 2-3 min gives blood bust, but for short term. After some time - say 2-3 years of training that goes down, as your body learns how to deal with pressure.